# Finding IP of servers

Tags: sockets, udp, multicast, broadcast

I am learning about sockets and client-server applications.  It seems as if the recommended approach is that the server should have a fixed IP address so that the client can find it.  Is this correct?  It seems as if there should be some type of startup technique where on initialization a program on the server (or the client) could generally broadcast their IP addresses to the other computers on the network, so that in case the server IP address changes the clients can still find it.  Is this possible?  I believe that "multicast" may be helpful, but it seems as if that is not always supported and/or the routers/switches must be configured to accept this or the technique would fail.  Is this correct?  I see that there are ways to perhaps use UDP to broadcast to any computer on the network, but it's not clear to me how the recipient computers can access this in a clear manner without a socket already set up - wouldn't there be confusion if other computers are already broadcasting on the same port?  Is it just a protocol issue for the program to sort out to recognize the received packets?  Do I just need to learn more about sockets?  Any and all suggestions/pointers for where I could look would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I am learning about sockets and client-server applications. It seems
>   as if the recommended approach is that the server should have a fixed
>   IP address so that the client can find it. Is this correct?

Yes, it is.

> It seems as if there should be some type of startup technique where on
>   initialization a program on the server (or the client) could generally
>   broadcast their IP addresses to the other computers on the network, so
>   that in case the server IP address changes the clients can still find
>   it. Is this possible?

Yes, it is.

> I believe that "multicast" may be helpful, but it seems as if that is
>   not always supported and/or the routers/switches must be configured to
>   accept this or the technique would fail. Is this correct?

No, multicast is not really helpful here, you mentioned why, and you should know multicast address in advance.

> I see that there are ways to perhaps use UDP to broadcast to any
>   computer on the network, but it's not clear to me how the recipient
>   computers can access this in a clear manner without a socket already
>   set up - wouldn't there be confusion if other computers are already
>   broadcasting on the same port?

You just advertise your clients once in a while, for example every 5 secs or every 1 min, whatever interval you find ok. If someone sends on this port too - then you should use some unique structure, magic numbers and so on to distinguish one packets from another.

> Is it just a protocol issue for the program to sort out to recognize
>   the received packets?

Yes, it is. On UDP.

> Do I just need to learn more about sockets?

Absolutly yes. I suggest this book: [Unix Network programming](http://books.google.ru/books/about/UNIX_Network_Programming.html?hl=ru&id=ptSC4LpwGA0C), it is good, even if you running non-UNIX environment.